# inbound-channel-adapter local-directory & message

Tags: ftp, spring-integration, adaptor

We have web application and want to use ftp:inbound-channel-adapter to read the files from ftp & create a message & send it to a channel

1. When **local-directory** is set to local-directory="#servletContext.getRealPath('')}/temp/inFtp" it gives 
   Message generated is 
   *GenericMessage [payload={applicationDeployPath}\temp\inFtp\xyz.stagging.dat, headers={timestamp=1444812027516, id=9b5f1581-bfd2-6690-d4ea-e7398e8ecbd6}]*

But directory is not created, i checked i have full permission here.
The path [{applicationDeployPath}\temp\inFtp] **does not denote a properly accessible directory.**

2. In Message i want to send some more fields as payload having value from property file as per environment, How can I do that?

   ```
   <int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInboundAdaptor"
       channel="ftpInboundChannel"
       session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
       filename-pattern="*.stagging.dat"
       delete-remote-files="false"
       remote-directory="/stagging/"
       local-directory="#servletContext.getRealPath('')}/temp/inFtp"
       auto-create-local-directory="true">
       <int:poller  fixed-rate="1000"/>
   </int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
   ```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `local-directory` is only evaluated once (and created if necessary), at initialization time, not for every message.

I am surprised the context even initializes; this syntax looks bad:

```
local-directory="#servletContext.getRealPath('')}/temp/inFtp"
```

If you mean

```
local-directory="#{servletContext.getRealPath('')}/temp/inFtp"
```

it would only work if you have some bean called `servletContext`.

If you mean

```
local-directory="#servletContext.getRealPath('')/temp/inFtp"
```

you would need a variable `servletContext` in the evaluation context.

> it gives Message generated is GenericMessage [payload={applicationDeployPath}\temp\inFtp\xyz.stagging.dat, headers={timestamp=1444812027516, id=9b5f1581-bfd2-6690-d4ea-e7398e8ecbd6}]

If it's actually generating that message, it must have created that directory.

It's not clear what you mean by

> I want to send some more fields as payload

The payload is a `File`.

If you want to change the payload to something else containing the file and other fields, use a transformer.

Comment: Thanks Gary, For adding extra information in message payload I will use the transformer. 

It was typo while writing  the question. the real config was 
`local-directory="#{servletContext.getRealPath('')}/temp/inFtp"` 
as you also mentioned. And the folder was getting created and file was getting copied as expected but since it was shared temp space it was getting cleared by another process.